# Bash/Nawk whitespace problems

Tags: bash, shell, awk, runtime-error, random-walk

I have 100 datafiles, each with 1000 rows, and they all look something like this:

```
0       0   0   0
1       0   1   0
2       0   1   -1
3       0   1   -2
4       1   1   -2
5       1   1   -3
6       1   0   -3
7       2   0   -3
8       2   0   -4
9       3   0   -4
10      4   0   -4
.
.
.
999     1   47  -21
1000        2   47  -21
```

I have developed a script which is supposed to take the square of each value in columns 2,3,4, and then sum and square root them.
Like so:

```
temp = ($t1*$t1) + ($t2*$t2) + ($t3*$t3)
calc = $calc + sqrt ($temp)
```

It then calculates the square of that value, and averages these numbers over every data-file to output the average "calc" for each row and average "fluc" for each row.

The meaning of these numbers is this:
The first number is the step number, the next three are coordinates on the x, y and z axis respectively. I am trying to find the distance the "steps" have taken me from the origin, this is calculated with the formula `r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`. Next I need the fluctuation of r, which is calculated as `f = r^4` or `f = (r^2)^2`. 
These must be averages over the 100 data files, which leads me to:

```
r = r + sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
avg = r/s
```

and similarly for f where s is the number of read data files which I figure out using `sum=$(ls -l *.data | wc -l)`. 
Finally, my last calculation is the deviation between the expected `r` and the average `r`, which is calculated as `stddev = sqrt(fluc - (r^2)^2)` outside of the loop using final values.

The script I created is:

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=$(ls -l *.data | wc -l)
paste -d"\t" *.data | nawk -v s="$sum" '{
    for(i=0;i<=s-1;i++)
    {
        t1 = 2+(i*4)
        t2 = 3+(i*4)
        t3 = 4+(i*4)
        temp = ($t1*$t1) + ($t2*$t2) + ($t3*$t3)
        calc = $calc + sqrt ($temp)
        fluc = $fluc + ($calc*$calc)
    }
    stddev = sqrt(($calc^2) - ($fluc))
    print $1" "calc/s" "fluc/s" "stddev
    temp=0
    calc=0
    stddev=0
}'
```

Unfortunately, part way through I receive an error:

```
nawk: cmd. line:9: (FILENAME=- FNR=3) fatal: attempt to access field -1
```

I am not experienced enough with awk to be able to figure out exactly where I am going wrong, could someone point me in the right direction or give me a better script?

The expected output is one file with:

```
0 0 0 0
1 (calc for all 1's) (fluc for all 1's) (stddev for all 1's)
2 (calc for all 2's) (fluc for all 2's) (stddev for all 2's)
.
.
.
```

Comment: I *think* I get it, but it would be very helpful if you'd show your expected output as well, so that if we come up with an alternative, we know whether we're actually interpreting your requirements correctly.

Comment: Added in more explanation, thank you!

Comment: I'm note quite sure what e.g. _(calc for all 1's)_ means. Do you want todo your statistics for all lines having a "1" in the first column no matter what file they come from? This would mean that in your desired result the enumeraration would go up to 1000?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. It calculates the average distance for all walks after the first step, second step and so on.

Comment: So it's not accumalative across step boundary?

Comment: Yes, just for each step. So all 1's, all 2's, all 3's.
The reason my script has a += is because it jumps between steps. (or at least its supposed to with the (i*4)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script should do what you want. The only thing that might not work yet is the choice of delimiters. In your original script you seem to have tabs. My solution assumes spaces. But changing that should not be a problem.

It simply pipes all files sequentially into the `nawk` without counting the files first. I understand that this is not required. Instead of trying to keep track of positions in the file it uses arrays to store seperate statistical data for each step. In the end it iterates over all step indexes found and outputs them. Since the iteration is not sorted there is another pipe into a Unix `sort` call which handles this.

```
#!/bin/bash
# pipe the data of all files into the nawk processor
cat *.data | nawk ' 
BEGIN { 
  FS=" "                         # set the delimiter for the columns
} 
{
  step = $1                      # step is in column 1
  temp = $2*$2 + $3*$3 + $4*$4

  # use arrays indexed by step to store data
  calc[step] = calc[step] + sqrt (temp)
  fluc[step] = fluc[step] + calc[step]*calc[step]
  count[step] = count[step] + 1   # count the number of samples seen for a step
}
END {
  # iterate over all existing steps (this is not sorted!)
  for (i in count) {
    stddev = sqrt((calc[i] * calc[i]) + (fluc[i] * fluc[i]))
    print i" "calc[i]/count[i]" "fluc[i]/count[i]" "stddev
  }
}' | sort -n -k 1 # that' why we sort here: first column "-k 1" and numerically "-n"
```

**EDIT**

As sugested by @edmorton `awk` can take care of loading the files itself. The following enhanced version removes the call to `cat` and instead passes the file pattern as parameter to `nawk`. Also, as suggested by @NictraSavios the new version introduces a special handling for the output of the statistics of the last step. Note that the gathering of the statistics is still done for all steps. It's a little difficult to suppress this during the reading of the data since at that point we don't know yet what the last step will be. Although this *can* be done with some extra effort you would probably loose a lot of robustness of your data handling since right now the script does not make any assumptions about:

- the number of files provided,
- the order of the files processed,
- the number of steps in each file,
- the order of the steps in a file,
- the completeness of steps as a range without "holes".

Enhanced script:

```
#!/bin/bash
nawk ' 
BEGIN { 
  FS=" "   # set the delimiter for the columns (not really required for space which is the default)
  maxstep = -1
} 
{
  step = $1                      # step is in column 1
  temp = $2*$2 + $3*$3 + $4*$4

  # remember maximum step for selected output
  if (step > maxstep)
    maxstep = step

  # use arrays indexed by step to store data
  calc[step] = calc[step] + sqrt (temp)
  fluc[step] = fluc[step] + calc[step]*calc[step]
  count[step] = count[step] + 1   # count the number of samples seen for a step
}
END {
  # iterate over all existing steps (this is not sorted!)
  for (i in count) {
    stddev = sqrt((calc[i] * calc[i]) + (fluc[i] * fluc[i]))
    if (i == maxstep)
      # handle the last step in a special way
      print i" "calc[i]/count[i]" "fluc[i]/count[i]" "stddev
    else
      # this is the normal handling
      print i" "calc[i]/count[i]
  }
}' *.data | sort -n -k 1 # that' why we sort here: first column "-k 1" and numerically "-n"
```

Comment: Lose the UUOC and pipe as awk is perfectly capable of opening files, and `" "` is the default FS so no need to set it explicitly.

Comment: I think he set it explicitly to allow me to change it to tabs easily.

Comment: The fluctuation seems to be gigantic, and how would I make the standard deviation only operate on the last step? (It's all thats needed)

Comment: See an approach of handling the last step in my updated answer.

Comment: @NictraSavios but you don't need to change it to tabs. The default works just fine for any white space, that's the point of the default.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
awk -f c.awk *.data
```

where `c.awk` is

```
{
    j=FNR
    temp=$2*$2+$3*$3+$4*$4
    calc[j]=calc[j]+sqrt(temp)
    fluc[j]=fluc[j]+calc[j]*calc[j]
}

END {
    N=ARGIND
    for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) {
        stdev=sqrt(fluc[i]-calc[i]*calc[i])
        print i-1,calc[i]/N,fluc[i]/N,stdev
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, what I was trying to do is keep a running score of the fluctuations, or "calc^2", and then average them at the end, the standard deviation is then the running total of fluc minus calc squared. Basically, my fluc shouldn't be squared.

Comment: You have look closely by what @Håkon's and my approach differ: In Håkon's answer the statistics are computed _per file_. In my solution the statistics are gathered for each step _across the files_. Functionally, this is completely different!

Comment: @MarcusRickert I tested your code now on some sample data, and it produces exactly the same result as mine, provided you change your formula for `stdev` according to @NictraSavios last update..

Comment: @MarcusRickert Sorry, I realized now that I had tested my coded using exactly as many input files as there were rows in each file.. So it did not work if I reduced the number of files. However, I think I have fixed the bug now, see updated version..

Comment: @HåkonHægland I was wrong with my remark since I thought that `FNR` contained the file index of the input files. But it actually contains the record number. So our versions should be equivalent in the case that line `i` actually always contains the values for step `i`.